# Why firefox addon has no valid entry point?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I make Firefox addon using JPM, and when try to run it in dev mode:

```
jpm run -b $(which firefox)
```

have a message:

```
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on bgworker
JPM [error] Error: The addon has no valid entry point. Either create an entry point at `./index.js`, or set the `main` property to a valid path in your addon.
```

But in my addon xpi package exist `./index.js`.

I even try to write

```
"main": "./index.js"
```

in `package.json`.

I think there is no problem in my addon code but in my environment.

Using `Xubuntu 15.10 x64, JPM 1.0.7`.

Comment: Without code, a [mcve], this question may be off-topic: : Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: *How to create a [mcve], [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That means enough code that *completely* reproduces the problem.

Comment: You should at least give the output of `ls -R` from the folder you run jpm...